# How to move/rename uploaded file?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload

I followed [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) for uploading a file in my JSF2 application.
The application works fine but I am unhappy with one aspect.
While rebuilding the request, the File sent via request is saved somewhere on the disk.

Even though the file is saved I need to rename the file with a name which is available after entering the Managed Bean containing the action method.

Therefore I decided to create a new file with de desired name, copy the already saved file, and then delete the unneeded one.

```
private File uploadFile;
//...
try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uploadFile));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        bw.write(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e){}
```

The new file appears in the desired location but this error is thrown when I'm trying to open the file: *"Invalid or unsupported PNG file"*

These are my questions:

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem?
2. Is this solution the best way to upload a picture? Is there a reason to save the file before the business logic when there may be need to resize the picture or the desired name is not available yet.

**LE:**
I know abot [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html) as well but I'm trying to do this *mojarra* only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Reader` and `Writer` when you deal with binary files like images. Use streams: `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. And the best variant is to use @Perception solution with `renameTo` method.

Readers read file as if it consists of characters (e.g. txt, properties, yaml files). Image files are not characters, they are binary and you must use streams for that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a rename method built into `java.io.File` object already, I'd be surprised if it didn't work for your situation.

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest)

    Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

    Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: 
    The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to 
    another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the
    destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always
    be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.
```

You can also check if a file exists before saving it, and you can use the ImageIO class to do validations on the uploaded file before performing the initial save.